# can we call procedure within function and can call function within procedure?

Tags: sql

In oracle plsql ,can we call procedure within function and vice versa i.e. can call function within procedure?

Anyone please let me know with example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Functions can be called from Procedure whereas Procedures cannot be called from Function.